# Colours plate view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Using `objective-c/swift` , we have to create a colours plate ,that means some user interface object, that when you move your finger across ,you get some `RGB` output for the current colour .

So , i can use some costume class(which i am looking for) , or create some view with code, that have all the colours in it.

I couldn't find my way with any of this options, and be happy to hear about one.
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article about that, so you can do that with an image :

http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/